# How to get current tasks for custom Session in Alamofire 5

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, afnetworking

Previously I used AFNetworking and could easily get all the tasks for current session by `tasks` property. I'm trying to migrate to Alamofire 5 and I can't find the same property or way how to get all the tasks.
I create the session like this

```
let session: Session = {
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.af.default
    return Session(configuration: configuration)
}()
```

I'd like to check does my session contain any active tasks

Comment: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/Session.swift#L69 : `requestTaskMap`, `activeRequests`, none of these is what you are looking for?

Comment: Hello, thx for your answer. I saw them, but I can't get access from my custom Session property because they both are inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. If you need to perform actions on all of the currently ongoing `Request`s, you can use `Session.withAllRequests`. If all you need to do is cancel all `Request`s you can use `Session.cancelAllRequests`. Otherwise you should never access, much less interact with, the `URLSessionTask`s that underly an Alamofire `Session`.